# Can't send any email with Nodemailer package in Node js

Tags: javascript, nodemailer

I'm trying to send an email from my Node js application with nodemailer package, but I'm getting an unexpected problem.
I've just read several topic about the same problem and they worked for my gmail account, but actually I would like to use this service with an Aruba email.
This is the interested piece of code:

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
//const smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');
const config = require('./config.json');
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtps.aruba.it",
    logger: true,
    debug:true,
    secure: true,
    port: config.Mail.MAIL_PORT,
    auth: {
      user: config.Mail.MAIL_ADDRESS,
      pass: config.Mail.MAIL_PASSWORD 
    },
    tls:{
      minVersion: 'TLSv1',
      ciphers:'HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!eNULL:@STRENGTH:!DH:!kEDH'
    }
});

    let mailOptions = {
        from: config.Mail.MAIL_ADDRESS,
        to: config.Mail.MAIL_DEST,
        subject: config.Mail.MAIL_CONFIRM_SIGIN_SUBJECT,
        text: "Something"
 
 
  };
 
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
 
 
      if (error) {
 
 
        console.log(error);
 
 
      } else {
 
 
        console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
 
 
      }
 
 
    });
```

The console output is this one:

```
{
  code: 'EAUTH',
  response: '535 5.7.0 bkvxnow6m4Pmf ...authentication rejected',
  responseCode: 535,
  command: 'AUTH PLAIN'
}
[2022-04-05 15:17:30] INFO  [ljqdiec7p84] Connection closed
```

Comment: Since the error message is related to authentication you could try printing your `config` variable to check if it actually contains your right credentials, if it does, you could also check some configurations on your mail provider service, it is possible that it is blocking connections from nodemailer as sometimes gmail does.

Comment: It says here your auth object are wrong, you should check your config with Aruba IT support. Try to get from their feedback and asked why the error occur. If you ask me which mail provider I'm would like to use. I will recommend sendgrid and mailgun.